# Login in Asp.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-identity

Question on how to properly login in Asp.NET Core V2.  I am using ASP.NET Identity.

My OnPostAsync() method is below.  My code successfully takes the user's name and pwd, calls signin manager, and is successfully returning a true.  I would think that the proper way to login is to call SigninPasswordAsync.  A succeeded result comes back.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }
        var userName = Request.Form["UserName"];
        var pwd = Request.Form["Password"];
        var appUser = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = userName };
        var signin = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, pwd, true, false);
        if (signin.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("/Account/LoggedIn");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToPage("/Account/Login");
        }
    }
```

So, once the redirect happens, it redirects to the LoggedIn razor page.  The contents of the PageModel is below.  The problem is the using the [Authorize] attribute causes the page to not load and be redirect to the Login page, which is what I would expect if the conditions of the [Authorize] attribute are met.  The authorize conditions are not being met.  Digging into this seems to indicate that the HttpContext.User doesn't seem to have much/any content in it.  I am assuming that I need to call something besides the SigninPasswordAsync method or use a different attribute.  Thoughts?  Do I need to do something else?  I'm lost on what to do at this point, so any thoughts are appreciated.  Thanks.

```
[Authorize]
public class LoggedInModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
        var use = HttpContext.User;
    }
}
```

---

**** Update ****************************

---

I am adding the following content from my Startup.cs file:

```
    public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
       .SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        Configuration = builder.Build();
        services.AddDbContext<PooperAppDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<PooperAppDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddScoped<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;

            // Lockout settings
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            // User settings
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(150);
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login"; // If the LoginPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Login
            options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout"; // If the LogoutPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Logout
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied"; // If the AccessDeniedPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/AccessDenied
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });

        services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            //options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/MembersOnly");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Account/Logout");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Account/LoggedIn", "PooperBasic, PooperPayer"); // with policy
            //options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Pages/Admin/Login"); // excluded page

            //options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToFolder("/Public"); // just for completeness
        });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Administrator"));
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            var options = new RewriteOptions()
                .AddRedirectToHttps();
        }
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseAuthentication();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to put `app.UseAuthentication()` first before `app.UserMvc()` in the `Configure()` method?

Comment: I would also accept @DavidLiang 's answer, but don't know how to accept a comment.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Marking it useful is fine. :) Have fun programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `UseAuthentication` **before** `UseMvc`. All middleware runs as part of a pipeline, so in your case the authentication middleware is not being called when you expect.

Have a look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware?tabs=aspnetcore2x) for a good description of the middleware pipeline.

Note: You should not need your call to `services.AddScoped<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();` as this will be handled by the `AddIdentity` stuff.